# Start a .txt or a .ahk in C language

Tags: c, autohotkey, txt

I want a program that opens a notepad that has a specific .txt opened and he can write paste stuff into it than closes and saves it, than the program reads from it and opens it again after it modified it.

I know how to modify it and read it, that is not what I want right now.
I don't know how to make that it opens the `test.txt` that I have.

I'm trying someting like `ShellExecute(open, NULL, "test.txt", NULL, NULL, 0);`, `system("start test.txt");` or `system("\"C:\\the\\full\\path\\test.txt\"");` but nothing works, the best I got is when it opens a **cmd** with the programs name being "test.txt"

later I tried opening a `.ahk` with C but that failed too. The same happened it started a cmd with a name: "myfile.ahk".

Again I just want to be able to start any kind of third party, thank you!

EDIT: [0x464e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813732/0x464e)'s comment helped, so thank you! i used this *(if anyone sees this in the future)*: `_execl("C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe","C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe","test.txt", NULL);`

Comment: This is operating system specific. On Linux, it won't work. If so allowed, consider using the [GTK](http://gtk.org/) GUI toolkit. Remember that some computers (including most Internet servers) don't even have a screen. A possibility could be to use some HTTP server library, such as [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) and take advantage of web browsers; this requires learning about [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). Please provide some [mre] in your next question

Comment: if you want to open notepad why don't you open notepad?

Comment: You're not "starting a file", you're starting a program and passing in a file. In the case of your text file, you probably mean starting Notepad.exe, and passing in your text file. In the case of your AHK script, you mean starting Autohotkey.exe and passing in your .ahk file.

Comment: Why not use FileAppend. No need to open the file in Notepad.